# How to click the page link with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

My error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"entrar"}
```

I have the html below:

```
<a role="menuitem" href="/login" class="_yce4s5">
  <div class="_hgs47m">
     <div class="_10ejfg4u">
       <div>
         Entrar
       </div>
     </div>
 </div> 
</a>
```

I click on the then link entrar, the following code in selenium with python:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Entrar')
element.click()
```

But It raises this NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Can you share the url ?

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback

Comment: Because your text is in the <div> tag which contains no link. You would want to search for the <a tag above through another method (xpath/class/bs4/requests)

Comment: Do what @The BrownBatman says. Or you can find the <div> as you are currently doing and then go get the <a> tag by going to a parent node twice.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Entrar')` # Capital `E`

Comment: I change Capital E, but the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use Upper case for the first letter? like `'Entrar'` instead of `'entrar'`

Comment: Thank you but it is not the solution.

Comment: @DaviLuis, try `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Entrar')`. The anchor tag contains other tags apart from the text.

Answer (score 1):

You might try `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('entrar')` because there is probably other text in your link. I like getting element by xpath. It's pretty easy. If you have Firefox just get the add-on xpath finder to find the xpath to any element on a web page.

Answer (score 1):

To click the page link with text as **Entrar** as the element is a dynamic element ou have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[role='menuitem'][href='/login'] > div > div > div"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@role='menuitem' and @href='/login']//div[normalize-space()='Entrar']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```